# Reported CPU frequency is lower than what the hardware specs are

Tags: linux, cpu, cpufreq

My Linux computer with custom kernel configuration seems slow. Even `make menuconfig` of Linux kernel is as slow as I can see redrawing of the menu. When I run `cpupower frequency-info`, frequency is below 150 MHz. But the minimum frequency on this CPU is 500 MHz. This is an Intel® Pentium® quad core processor N3540 (up to 2.66 GHz). I have never seen something like this.

Why is the frequency so low? I did not touched cpu-freq configuration since boot. The computer is resumed from sleep-to-ram.

I can set the frequency manually but it is fixed at (about) 64 MHz.

```
$ LANG= cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 500 MHz - 2.67 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 500 MHz and 1.07 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 129 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

`lscpu` output is created when the computer is OK.

```
$ LANG= lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               55
Model name:          Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3540  @ 2.16GHz
Stepping:            8
CPU MHz:             618.821
CPU max MHz:         2665.6001
CPU min MHz:         499.8000
BogoMIPS:            4331.60
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           24K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
```

Comment: Have you tried using an alternative govenor? I agree its weird that you are able to set an alternative govenor (like ondemand) which I suspect will fix your performance issues.  Also, what model CPU fo you have?

Comment: @davidgo, when I set `intel_pstate` to passive, I can change frequency manually. It if fixed at 64 MHz (±16 MHz) and I can't change it. I rebooted the computer and it is OK now.

Comment: I wonder if cpu-freq was misreporting. Note the CPU MHz output of lscpu.

Comment: @davidgo The lscpu output is new, without the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU frequency can be outside the limits, because the processor itself will slow
itself down if the load is light enough, regardless of the parameters.

You should only worry if the CPU frequency does not go up very quickly when
there is actual work to do. But if it does not, below are some possibilities:

- A battery issue, when the battery is really low and not charging.
- General OS confusion that may be fixed by unplugging the power cord and plugging
  it back in again (or reboot).
- Issues with CPU cooling, which may happen even when the laptop case is not
  even warm. So check sensors.
- A serious problem requiring a repair-shop.

Comment: Sensors are between 50 and 60 °C.

Comment: This is good, but the sensors can still miss-out on the problem.